# ColdFusion and neo4j examples

Tags: coldfusion, neo4j, coldfusion-11

Does anyone have an example of ColdFusion working with neo4j (or some other graph db)?

The common practice is to have an application service connect to a db. In CF it looks like the code below. One can then output the data.

```
<cfquery...>
    select * from tbl where x=y
</cfquery>
```

What I'm looking for is a way to connect to and 'consume' graph data, such that I can feed it to a UI that displays the graph connections.

I am currently at step 1. How do I connect to a db (I'm liking neo4j) so I can pass a query and get something back. Ideally something like:

```
<cfquery ... >
    MATCH (node) 
    RETURN node.propertyA, node.propertyB
</cfquery>
```

Is it even possible?

Comment: What you have tried/done so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: see: http://hackersome.com/p/bpanulla/cf_neo4j

Answer (score 3):

I would use CFHTTP and use Neo4j's REST endpoint to query Neo4j.

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-cypher.html